# Google Books Preview not showing Book Image Link on secured https but working on http.. in Google Chrome and Touch browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-books

I have a Google book preview embedded on my website but noticed a strange thing and needed help. 
I if i view the page on a secured http connection , the Image Book preview links shows... Which is what i want.

But when i view the same site on my a NOT secured http connection 
The preview link does not work..

This is my code snippet

```
<script src="http://books.google.com/books/previewlib.js"></script>
... <!-- html codes  -->
<script>GBS_setLanguage('en');</script>
<script>GBS_insertPreviewButtonPopup('{{subID}}');</script> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span title="  1740202872">High School Fundamentals of English</span></li>
```

I would have pasted the images here but not gotten to reputation to add image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make sure you include the jquery api first before including the google books api.

you can include the script like this:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://books.google.com/books/previewlib.js"></script>
```

then, add this:

```
... <!-- html codes  -->
<script>GBS_setLanguage('en');</script>
<script>GBS_insertPreviewButtonPopup('{{subID}}');</script> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span title="  1740202872">High School Fundamentals of English</span></li>
```